# File upload connection reset with Ninja Forms on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, connection-reset

I'm using Ninja Forms plugin in WordPress. I have the add-on File Upload. I am testing the form for large uploads since the site's front end has a file submission form. I tried to upload a 200mb single file, but it keeps on resetting on 5% - 10%. I tried multiple file that totals to 200mb, it was completed but it was less than 50mb per file.

I have this on my user.ini (GoDaddy Wordpress Builder Config file):

```
memory_limit = 2000M
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
post_max_size = 2000M
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 300
memory_limit = 64M
```

Comment: Can you replicate this locally? Is there anything in your host's error logs?

Comment: @halfer I'm working with a live site. There's no error log visible here but on Chrome I get ERR: CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: OK, you need to try it on another host. At the moment, presumably, you don't know if it is a problem with your code or your server.

Comment: There was a previous plugin "Gravity Forms", it worked on that(uploaded 200mb single file). But I had problems with the mobile view of Gravity Forms. So, I used Ninja Forms.

Comment: Do they have a support channel? They might have experience running it on GoDaddy, and perhaps can advise better than people here. Nevertheless, I would _still_ copy the whole site to my local machine to work on it, to satisfy myself that it works well.